# Cannot read properties of undefined (the general state is undefined)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vercel

I just finished a small project and I tried to publish it on Vercel, the project works without errors locally, but on the server I get the error: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'notes')", apparently not It recognizes the state that I have in my application, this would be my useNotes file:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { NotesContext } from "../context/NotesContext";

export const useNotes = () => {
    const { notestate, toggleNote, addNote, changeState, handleDeleteNote } = useContext(NotesContext);

    const { notes } = notestate;

    return {
        noteGeneral: notestate,
        notes: notes,
        notinteresting: notes?.filter(note => !note?.interesting).length,
        interesting: notes?.filter(note => note?.interesting === true).length,
        lisInteresting: notes?.filter(note => note?.interesting === true),
        listNotInteresting: notes?.filter(note => note?.interesting === false),
        toggleNote,
        addNote,
        changeState,
        handleDeleteNote
    }

}
```

this would be the context of my application:

```
import { createContext } from "react";
import { Note, NoteState } from "../interfaces/interfaces";


export type NoteContextProps = {
    notestate: NoteState,
    toggleNote: (id: number) => void;
    addNote: (note: Note) => void;
    changeState: (action: string) => void;
    handleDeleteNote: (id: number) => void;
}

export const NotesContext = createContext<NoteContextProps>({} as NoteContextProps);
```

and this is the provider of my application

```
import { useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';
import { Note, NoteState } from '../interfaces/interfaces';
import { NoteReducer } from './NoteReducer';
import { NotesContext } from './NotesContext';
import { DateNote } from '../../helpers/DateNote';

const { today } = DateNote();

const INITIAL_STATE: NoteState = {
    notesCount: 2,
    notes: [
        {
            id: 1,
            description: 'Welcome to NotesApp, here you can write all the notes you want. If you liked the project leave a comment on my social networks :)',
            interesting: true,
            title: 'Hello there',
            created: today
        },
    ],
    active: 'All',
}

interface props {
    children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[]
}

const NotesProvider = ({ children }: props) => {

    const localData = localStorage.getItem('notes');

    const toggleNote = (id: number) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'toggleInteresting', payload: { id } })
    }

    const addNote = (note: Note) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'addNote', payload: note })
    }

    const changeState = (active: string) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'changeState', payload: active })
    }

    const handleDeleteNote = (id: number) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'deleteNote', payload: { id } })
    }

    const [notestate, dispatch] = useReducer(NoteReducer, INITIAL_STATE, () => {
        return localData ? JSON.parse(localData) : localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(INITIAL_STATE))
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(notestate))
    }, [notestate])

    return (
        <NotesContext.Provider value={{ toggleNote, addNote, changeState, handleDeleteNote, notestate }}>
            {children}
        </NotesContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default NotesProvider;
```

I am storing the state of my application in Localstorage.

I've been looking for the solution for more than two days but I can't find it

Answer (score 0):

```
 const [notestate, dispatch] = useReducer(NoteReducer, INITIAL_STATE, () => {
        return localData ? JSON.parse(localData) : localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(INITIAL_STATE))
    });
```

I think here when there is no local data, the `notestate` receives value from localStorage.setItem(), which is undefined, so the `notestate` will be undefined.

Comment: that is happening, when starting the application locally, it takes the INITIAL_STATE by default, but in Vercel it gives me undefined.